# UI Thread overload

Tags: android, android-layout, ui-thread

I'm working on an android application which use Anko DSL and kotlin and only one activity.

My first displayed view is a big view with a main vertical scroll view which contains others scrollview (horizontal) and lot of things.

I've made a splashscreen view which puts itself above the main view at the beginning of activity.

This splashscreen contains a GIF and there are lags on mobile because the mainview is creating in the same time, so the UIthread is overloading.

How can I render my mainview without impacting my splashview ?
Is it possible ?

I think that I am not the only one must to want to show a screen splash during the rendering of the main view